# Rounding expected values - what's the expected integer?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Suppose I have an alphabet that consists of 3 letters: $A$, $B$, $C$. We create words by pulling letters from a bag. The probabilities that we pull these letters are: $0.5$, $0.4$, $0.1$.

When I create a 10-symbol word this way, I expect to have $5$, $4$, $1$ of each letter. This makes sense intuitively. But when the word is 5 letter long, the intuition breaks. The expected frequencies are now: $2.5$, $2$, $0.5$. Since I need an integer result, I have to round and there are 2 choices with supposedly equal probabilities: $3$, $2$, $0$ and $2$, $2$, $1$. But when I calculate the probability it appears to be different:

$$
   p(\text{"3A-2B-0C"}) = 0.5^3 \times 0.2^2 \times \frac{10!}{3!2!} = 0.2
$$
and
$$
   p(\text{"2A-2B-1C"}) = 0.5^2 \times 0.2^2 \times 0.1 \times \frac{10!}{2!2!} = 0.12
$$

How should I go about figuring out the most probable combination rounded to integer?

PS: I'm trying to apply thins in Analytical Chemistry - figure out the most abundant combination of isotopes (they correspond to A, B, C) in a molecule of 5 atoms.

Comment: Why would you expect the two "rounded events" to be equally probable?  The expected outcome averages over a whole lot of outcomes which are not equally probable.  Look at the case of a weighted die.  Just because the expected value happens to comes out between two integer values is no reason to imagine that the two integers must be equally probable.

Comment: I'm slowly starting to realize this.. Eventually I'd have to come up with a universal algorithm to decide which _integer_ combination is the most probable. Rephrased the question.

Comment: To stress:  there's also no reason to imagine that the two "rounded cases" are even probable.  Suppose you had a die that could only come up $1$ or $6$ with equal probability.  Of course the expected value is $3.5$, as for a fair die.  But neither $3$ nor $4$ is even possible.  Expected value is great, but it tells you very little about what specific outcomes are actually likely.

Comment: In your example both 3 and 4 are possible, not sure why you're saying they're not. Or did you mean _probable_? "_Expected value is great, but it tells you very little about what specific outcomes are actually likely_." - but these are close concepts.. If I know the expected value, I'm already in the ballpark of the likely outcome. At least in my scenario this seems like the case.

Comment: In my example, the probability of getting a $1$ or a $6$ is $\frac 12$ each.  All the other values are impossible  (probability $0$ if you prefer).

Comment: Again, it is simply not true that the expected value must be somewhere  near the most likely value.  Imagine, say, you had a (very generous) lottery where you had only a $\frac 1{1000}$ chance of winning but that winning got you a million dollars.  The expected value is a thousand dollars, but the most likely outcome (by a huge margin) is $0$.

Comment: I see what you're saying. But in your example with dice, you could've "rounded" to the closest possible value. So if your dice is not fair, and results in expected value = 4, then "rounding" it to 6 would give the likely result. I don't understand what other approach I can use to calculate the likely outcome.. When the word is long, the result seems to be consistent with the expected value. It's only when it's short - then the problems seem to arise. Though even in the long words there will probably be boundary cases when we'd have to deal with ties.

Comment: Not sure what point you are making.  In my example, you could let $2,3,4,5$ each have probability $10^{-10}$, lowering the probability of $1,6$ to compensate.  But who needs an ad hoc method when you can just read off the answer?  I think you are hoping for a general principle where none exists.  That said, in your particular example, I'd be surprised if the most probable state was very far from the expected case...multinomial distributions tend to look unimodular.  For small numbers of trials though, some oddities wouldn't surprise me.  So I'd search more broadly than just nearest neighbors.

Comment: In general, integer optimization problems are terrible, just for this reason.  You hope that continuous methods get you close, but they don't have to.  And it can be very hard to find isolated optima far from the continuous ones.

Comment: I see.. This sends the investigation into a whole new direction (c). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Again, in your particular case, I'd search near the continuous optimum. If (as expected) the probabilities drop off quickly as you get further from it, I'd be satisfied and just take the max.  If you absolutely need to be certain of your result, I'd search further and try to demonstrate the sort of monotonicity you need. But usually, strong numerical evidence is good enough.